# $\lim_{x\to a} x^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

How to find $\lim_{x\to b} x^{1\over n}$ $(n \in \mathbb{Z})$  without using that this function is continuous and without L'Hôpital's rule?
I tried to approximate it like this:
$\alpha$ > 0:
Let x = b + $\alpha$, then $(b + \alpha)^{1\over n} \leq$ $b^\frac{1}{n}$ + $ \frac{\alpha}{n \cdot b^{1\over n-1}}$
But I don't know how to approximate when $\alpha \le 0$?
Please, Help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use that elementary functions like $f(x) = x^{1/n}$ are continuous? These should be things that have to be proven before solving these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Math_QED  Just because our teachers gave us "limits of the functions" before "continuity of functions". That is the reason

Comment: Are you sure you can't assume that this function is continuous?

Comment: @Math_QED absolutely, I asked about it  today

Comment: Try to use an $\epsilon - \delta$ approach following the definition of limit (and the fact that you know in fact the limiting value...), but I don't know if it could be an appropriate exercise if you aren't even allowed to use continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $b>0:$

Use instead $u^n-v^n=(u-v)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}v+\cdots + v^{n-1})$, with $u=x^{1/n}$ and $v=b^{1/n}$. With $b>0$, at least, this will give you:

$$\left|x^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\right|=\frac{|x-b|}{x^{(n-1)/n}+x^{(n-2)/n}b^{1/n}+...+b^{(n-1)/n}}$$

If we bound $x>\frac{b}{2}$ then we get:

$$x^{(n-1)/n}+x^{(n-2)/n}b^{1/n}+\cdots+b^{(n-1)/n}>nb^{(n-1)/n}/2$$

and so:

$$\left|x^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\right| \leq \frac{2|x-b|}{nb^{(n-1)/n}}$$

Now, given $\epsilon>0$ pick a $\delta$ appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approximation is brilliant!